# Cannot find Await from akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have an error of importing Await from akka.io. Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "Project1"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.1.4"
```

Here is a part of a code:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.dispatch.Await
import akka.pattern.ask


//.......
private def resultId = {
    private val someActor = context.actorSelection("../someActor123") // defined in   Application object
    val future = someActor ? SomeMessage
    val result = Await.result(future, 1.timeout).asInstanceOf[String]
  }
```

It says object `Await is not a member of package akka.dispatch` and `value ? is not a member of akka.actor.ActorSelection` and `not found: value Await`

Of course, I reloaded it and did gen-idea.

Comment: It's now `scala.concurrent.Await` from [Await](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [@S.R.I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205936/s-r-i) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829050/cannot-find-await-from-akka#comment26021328_17829050) you should use `scala.concurrent.Await` instead of `akka.dispatch.Await`.

> value ? is not a member of akka.actor.ActorSelection

There is no `ask` pattern support for `ActorSelection` in version `2.1.4`. See [this commit](https://github.com/akka/akka/commit/7ea3044af87b28d654bfb955a39c8fd1d4e99e52#L4R79). Ask support for `ActorSelection` is available only after version `2.2`.

Comment: these are in different packages. is it the same Await as it was before?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: It's an unification between `akka` and `scala`. There are no more scala actors (akka actors are default actor implementation) an there are no more akka `Future`, `Promice`, `Await` and so on. There are only implementations for scala.concurrent traits. See [this commit](https://github.com/akka/akka/commit/0bf45a940397e0b95952905fe7421fdbd62726f5).

Comment: I'm confused. Is there any difference between scala akktors and akka.io actors? Or are they all the same thing?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: `scala.actors` are deprecated. See [feature list](http://www.scala-lang.org/2.10.2) for scala 2.10: `Akka Actors now part of the distribution. 
    scala.actors have been deprecated and the akka implementation is now included in the distribution. 
    See the actors migration project for more information.`

Comment: @MariusKavansky: `Future` (`Promise`, `Await` and so on) don't depends on actors and it's part of scala standard library itself. Akka actors depends on `Future` (and so on) from scala standard library. There **was** actors in scala standard library - now deprecated and where **was** independent `Future` (`Promise`, `Await` and so on) in akka - now switched to `Future` from scala standard library.

Comment: so, it's better to start using the newest version of akka.io, correct?

Comment: @senia, great - +1 for detail.

Comment: I still can't find ? supported in 2.3.3. See: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.3/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSelection